# How to print the first words of lines that contain a specific word?

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a file where each line contains a person's name, occupation, and duties separated by commas.
How could I print the name of the people who have a specific occupation?
So far i have

`awk -v val="barrister" '$0 ~ val' Occupation.txt`

for printing the lines that contain the occupation

But I dont know how I could make it so it only prints the line until the first comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Awk` works by applying actions specified within `{}` blocks to `records` (lines) *filtered* according to  `pattern`s (identified within //) that optionally precede action blocks.

Thus, the following command processes lines from `occupation.txt`, if they contain the string pattern "barrister", and prints the first `field` (column) `$1` from those lines. Lines not containing the search pattern are ignored.

(default field separator changed from space to comma, as pointed out by @tshiono)

```
awk ' BEGIN{FS = ","} /barrister/{print $1}' occupation.txt
```

equivalent to:

```
awk -F "," '/barrister/{print $1}' occupation.txt
```

tested on

`occupation.txt`:

```
John, barrister, early
Jane, barrister, late
Kevin, manager, early
Karen, manager, late
```

output:

```
John
Jane
```

Comment: As you are using the default field separator, the output will look like `John,` and `Jane,`.

Answer (score -1):

```bash
grep barrister Occupation.txt | \
  awk -F, '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: No need for grep once awk is in the picture